# CodeIgniter 3.1.9: Call to undefined function odbc_connect() in MacOS

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter, xampp, odbc

UPDATE: This question has been flagged as a question that has been solved already. But when checked, those previous "similar" questions require users to download the corresponding `.dll` file which is not applicable for macOS users and other answers did not explicitly elaborate on how to install needed extensions like pdo_sqlsrv, sqlsrv, and ODBC for XAMPP-installed PHP.

I'm trying to connect to MS SQL database using CodeIgniter 3.1.9 via ODBC:

```
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'x.x.x.x',
    'username' => 'sa',
    'password' => 'xxx',
    'database' => 'xxx',
    'dbdriver' => 'odbc'
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
An uncaught Exception was encountered
Type: Error

Message: Call to undefined function odbc_connect()

Filename: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/gpweb/system/database/drivers/odbc/odbc_driver.php

Line Number: 141
```

PHP is installed via XAMPP. I checked the `php.ini` file to get information about ODBC and the line below is disabled because of the semi-colon in the beginning:

```
;extension=php_pdo_odbc.dll
```

I know it is irrelevant because I'm running on MacOS and `.dll` files are for Windows (but I still tried enabling it and with more errors):

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Core Warning

Message: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/php_pdo_odbc.dll' - dlopen(/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/php_pdo_odbc.dll, 0x0009): tried: '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php_pdo_odbc.dll' (no such file), '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/php_pdo_odbc.dll' (no such file)

Filename: Unknown

Line Number: 0
```

Has anyone encountered this issue before and how did you solve it? How can you enable ODBC in MacOS with PHP installed using XAMPP?

Answer (score 0):

try `sudo apt-get install php-odbc`

Followed by restarting Apache.

Comment: This answer might help developers running on Windows but unfortunately, my question is for MacOS users.

Comment: use `sudo apt-get install php-odbc` in MacOS

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, macOS users that use XAMPP to install PHP have no way to install extensions like `sqlsrv`, `pdo_sqlsrv`, and `ODBC`, unlike in Windows, where they can download the necessary `.dll` files and enable extensions in the `php.ini`.

I've been using CodeIgniter 3.x.x for years to create web applications and MySQL as the database. I wanted to utilize the said PHP library with my other projects requiring MSSQL as the database since CI can do so, provided that you have installed the necessary extensions.

I have scoured the internet and there is really no definite solution to install extensions in XAMPP-installed PHP running macOS.

I gave up and installed PHP using homebrew instead. In your terminal, enter:

```
$ brew install php
```

Then installed `sqlsrv` extension (for M1 ARM64 users)

```
sudo CXXFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/unixodbc/include/" LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/lib/" pecl install sqlsrv
sudo CXXFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/unixodbc/include/" LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/lib/" pecl install pdo_sqlsrv
```

Then the `ODBC` extension:

```
HOMEBREW_NO_ENV_FILTERING=1 ACCEPT_EULA=Y
brew install msodbcsql17 mssql-tools
```

Since I cannot use the XAMPP-installed PHP, I have to use the CodeIgniter 4 to use the natively installed PHP:

```
composer create-project codeigniter4/appstarter project-root
```

After that, in the `/project/app/Config/Database.php` of my CodeIgniter 4 project, setup the connection to the database:

```
 public $default = [
    'DSN'      => '',
    'hostname' => 'x.x.x.x', // IP ADDRESS OF THE SQL SERVER
    'username' => 'xxx', // USERNAME
    'password' => 'xxx', // PASSWORD
    'database' => 'xxx', // NAME OF DATABASE
    'DBDriver' => 'SQLSRV', // DATABASE DRIVER TO BE USED
    'DBPrefix' => '',
    'pConnect' => false,
    'DBDebug'  => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'charset'  => 'utf8',
    'DBCollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swapPre'  => '',
    'encrypt'  => false,
    'compress' => false,
    'strictOn' => false,
    'failover' => [],
    'port'     => 1433, // DEFAULT PORT FOR SQL SERVER
];
```

This is not the solution to the original problem (XAMPP-installed PHP), but an alternative solution to connect to MSSQL database using PHP.

**REFERENCE:**

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/installation-tutorial-linux-mac?view=sql-server-ver16
- https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/installation/index.html

But still, if you found a way to install `sqlsrv` and `ODBC` extensions in XAMPP-installed PHP running macOS, please don't hesitate to post it here.